# Custom MemberShip Provider, override Create User

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to create my own "CreateUser" by overriding the MemberShipProvider-class method. Problem is that CreateUser is of datatype MembershipUser, and i have no interest in returning an MembershipUser, i only want to know if the user was created or not by returning a bool. How can i accomplish that in best way?

```
public override MembershipUser CreateUser(string name, string email)
    {
        User u = new User
        {
            Email = email,
            Name = name
        };
        gdb.Users.InsertOnSubmit(u);
        try
        {
            gdb.SubmitChanges();
            MailSender.NewMember("hej hopp");
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are writing a custom membership provider you must respect the signatures of the methods defined in the base class. So you must return an instance of `MembershipUser`. If in your application you don't do anything with the returned value of the `CreateUser` method you could return null or an instance of `MembershipUser` where you populate only the fields you want to need to use in the constructor.

Comment: That's the thing, when i register the user at first i don't have enough information to populate the MembershipUser's constructor, so i cant return an MemreshipUser-object.

Comment: Then use only the information you have. IIRC the arguments of the MembershipUser constructor are for most of them optional.